# Eclipse 2019-03 is showing this message: JRE Oracle Corporation/12.0.1 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, java-12

I am using Eclipse 2019-03 (current version as of now) and JDK 12 on Windows 10. Whenever I run any code, it runs everything fine. However, it also shows a message colored red. This is the message I am getting:

> JRE Oracle Corporation/12.0.1 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled

[Snapshot of the Eclipse console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJmK2.png)

Is there something I can do or should just ignore it?
Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the [Java 12 plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411) for eclipse.

Note that in eclipse 2019-06 and higher, that plugin isn't needed any more.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I updated the post now with information for eclipse 2019-06 and higher, however, that was not available at the time of writing that post.