# JRE Oracle Corporation/13 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled on Eclipse 06-2019 and Java 13

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have Windows 10, 64-bit. I have Java version 13, version date: 2019-09-17.

I have Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0).

I can compile and run codes. But when I try to debug a code I get this error message:

"JRE Oracle Corporation/13 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled."

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043359/eclipse-2019-03-is-showing-this-message-jre-oracle-corporation-12-0-1-is-not-su) someone asked a similar question in SO, one of the answers say that you need a plugin, but on Eclipse versions 06-2019 and higher you don't need a plugin.

My Eclipse version is 06-2019 (4.12.0). Why it doesn't work?

Comment: That link is about Java 12. For full Java 13 support you need Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) plus the patch from [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-13-support-eclipse-2019-09-413)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that Eclipse has not yet been updated to include Advanced Source Lookup for JRE 13.

My solution is to uncheck "Use advanced source lookup" (Last item in the Preferences>Java>Debug menu). The red warning message then no longer appears.

Answer (score 1):

The [Eclipse 2019.12/4.14 M1](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/) does have [Java 13 (and 14) support](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/jdt.php#Java_13)

> [Java 13](http://jdk.java.net/13/) is available and Eclipse JDT supports Java 13 for 4.14.
>   The release notably includes the following Java 13 features:
>
> - [JEP 354: Switch Expressions (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354).
> - [JEP 355: Text Blocks (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355).
>
> Please note that these are preview language feature and hence enable preview option should be on.
>   For an informal introduction of the support, please refer to [Java 13 Examples wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java13/Examples).

So try and upgrade, to check if "advanced source lookup" is available during a debug session.

Comment: I just re-installed my Eclipse to Eclpise Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0). Installed as described here: https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13-P-builds/ but I get error I can't install. I get this error message:
 "Eclipse PDE Source Patch with Java 13 support for 2019-09 development stream" is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed.
"Eclipse PDE Patch with Java 13 support for 2019-09 development stream" is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @Coder88 Can you try 4.14M1? https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.14M1-201910091800/

Comment: I have installed Version: 2019-12 (4.14) from the link you gave (eclipse-SDK-4.14M1-win32-x86_64.zip). But I get the same error when trying to debug ("JRE Oracle Corporation/13 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled"). I tried again after installing the builds in https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.14milestones/ as described, restarted Eclipse. But when debugging still get the same error.  ("JRE Oracle Corporation/13 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled"). I still don't get why it won't debug?

Comment: @Coder88 Strange. just for testing, would that work better with an AdoptJDK 13? (https://adoptopenjdk.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that [Eclipse 4.14](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/) does support the latest [Java SE 13.0.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
I experienced this very same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the answer by [@vonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) does solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Tomcat settings, On the Server Options of the tomcat- uncheck the Enable security option (i.e. [SSLEnabled](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html)) and then stop and start your tomcat.